# Event Sourcing and dictionary objects

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

How event sourcing can be combined with several types of dictionary objects like `Country`, `Region`, `Time Zone` etc. and dictionary types from particular domain model like `Budget` or `Availability` definitions. Some of dictionary objects should be possible to edit in admin UI but some not.

For example we decided, that we do not need admin UI for countries. Thus we do not need to implement `AddCountry`/`RemoveCountry` commands.

Should i generate set of `CountryAdded` events i.e. should i persist dictionary objects as stream of events? **Do we ever use source of truth other then event stream?**

---

In case i can go without event stream for dictionary objects, how you'll solve this problem:

> Display list of countries with the
>   number of users in each country.

In this case i need representation of `Country` objects in the read model with listener for `UserAdded` event.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use event sourcing as the persistence mechanism, then:

- event stream is the only source of truth (object snapshots generated from event stream could be used to improve the performance, but they are just the technique).
- When you use event sourcing, you don't need to generate event explicitly - just publish actual events generated while processing the command.
- if you have a predefined list of countries, that are never going to change, you can just hard-code and reference them by their country codes. However this implies that view model and UI know about that and countries are not going to change.

BTW I recommend posting questions like these to [DDD/CQRS group](http://groups.google.com/group/dddcqrs/topics). It's the most active community on the questions of CQRS/DDD/ES.

Comment: Thank you Rinat! You completely answered on my question. Thank you for pointing me on DDD/CQRS group. I've found many useful questions/answers. Will ask my future coming questions in this group.